# Missing dependency hive-builtins causes build failure with error code 410 for Oozie

Tags: apache, maven, hadoop

I try to build the oozie from the sources but failed to install. I want to install oozie and eagerly waiting to work with that .I am failing at this stage : when I given the cmd from oozie -3.3.3 directory:

```
bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests
```

I got this error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:55 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-05T14:05:27+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/372M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-hive: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-hive:jar:3.3.2: 
        Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.hive:hive-builtins:jar:0.13.1: 
        Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.hive:hive-builtins:jar:0.13.1: 
        Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hive:hive-builtins:pom:0.13.1 from/to Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): 
        Failed to transfer file: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/hive/hive-builtins/0.13.1/hive-builtins-0.13.1.pom. Return code is: 410 , ReasonPhrase:Gone.
```

FYI: In my system I have a working Environment of Hadoop 1.0.4 and the other tools:

- sqoop-1.4.6,
- apache-maven-3.3.3,
- pig-0.13.0,
- Hive-0.13.1,
- hbase-0.98.4 and
- Java - jdk1.7.0_45.

What am I missing or is misconfigured causing the build failure? Am I better served with a  pre-build version for oozie?

Comment: Looking at http://oozie.apache.org/ there is no 3.3.3 release. Where did you actually get your code from? Why are you trying to build it yourself? Any particular reason for not to use the latest version, 4.2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Codehaus](http://www.codehaus.org/) hosting platform was ended, i.e., their public Maven repository is gone, too. You should try to follow [their advice](http://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/) and add the following to your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file:

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>Codehaus repository</id>
    <name>codehaus-mule-repo</name>
    <url>
      https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
    </url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

This should use a backup repository to get the missing dependency.

I’m not sure about the repository ID that needs to be used. I have used the one from the [Oozie 3.3.2 POM](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=oozie.git;a=blob_plain;f=pom.xml;hb=refs/tags/release-3.3.2) above.