# building oozie: Unknown host repository.codehaus.org

Tags: oozie

I'm trying to build Oozie 4.2.0 downloaded from here: http://ftp.cixug.es/apache/oozie/4.2.0/oozie-4.2.0.tar.gz

After launching the build

```
bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-core:jar:4.2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.1.1 from/to Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): Unknown host repository.codehaus.org
```

From what I'm seeing on the Internet, codehause repository is not available any more. Is there a way to build Oozie without it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for the sake of helping people seeing this question in the future , you can resolve this through backing up this repo source with another source

The Codehaus hosting platform was ended, i.e., their public Maven repository is gone, too. You should try to follow their advice and add the following to your ~/.m2/settings.xml file:

```
<repositories>
     <repository>
       <id>Codehaus repository</id>
       <name>codehaus-mule-repo</name>
       <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
       </url>
       <layout>default</layout>
     </repository>
   </repositories>
```

This should use a backup repository to get the missing dependency.

Source : [Missing dependency hive-builtins causes build failure with error code 410 for Oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229585/missing-dependency-hive-builtins-causes-build-failure-with-error-code-410-for-oo)

Comment: The above definitely helped the final push to get it built. Just a note, on Mac OSX, I was only able to build when re-installing the old JDK 1.6 from Apple (https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) and using an archived version of Maven 3.0.1