# Maven Build Error on a Spring Project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a Spring MVC Project using Maven, but when I run maven compile i get an error (below).

This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.zodiac.qtp</groupId>
    <artifactId>QTPGenerator</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>QTPGenerator</name>
    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- EHcache dependencie -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>ibm.lotus</groupId>
              <artifactId>domingo</artifactId>
              <version>1.5.1</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zodiac.lotus</groupId>
        <artifactId>notes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-js-resources</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Search Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-analyzers</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- APACHE POI Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- necessary only if you are using WebDriver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- End Selenium Tests -->

        <!-- APAche POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END APAche POI -->

        <!-- PDF SEARCH -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- end PDF SEARCH -->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <!-- <configuration> <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see 
                        MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <!-- Aspects in src/main/java and src/main/aspects are added as default 
                        in the compile goal. Aspects in src/test/java and src/test/aspects are added 
                        as default in the test-compile goal. Aspects in src/main/java are added in 
                        the test-compile goal if weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder is set to true -->
                    <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>false</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>false</printSummary>
                    <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- IDE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <browser>*firefox</browser>
                    <suite>src/main/webapp/selenium/test-suite.xhtml</suite>
                    <results>${project.build.directory}/selenium.html</results>
                    <startURL>http://localhost:4444/</startURL>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
                        <version>2.25.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is Maven command output

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project QTPGenerator: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.zodiac.qtp:QTPGenerator:war:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.3.7.Final (compile), commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4 (compile), mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test), com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.2 (compile), ibm.lotus:domingo:jar:1.5.1 (compile), com.zodiac.lotus:notes:jar:1.0.0 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5 (compile), org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5 (compile), org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.4 (compile), org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.4 (compile), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided), net.sf.flexjson:flexjson:jar:2.1 (compile), org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1 (compile), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE (test), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE (compile), org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.9 (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.7.Final (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.7.Final (compile), org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final (compile), commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1 (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.1.Final (compile), javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA (compile), javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1 (compile), org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE (compile), commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.6 (compile), commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4 (compile), org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE (compile), commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1 (compile), commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2 (compile), javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:jar:1.2 (compile), org.glassfish.web:jstl-impl:jar:1.2 (compile), javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2 (provided), joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6 (compile), javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1 (provided), commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5 (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE (compile), org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13 (compile), javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.1 (compile), javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4 (compile), org.json:json:jar:20140107 (compile), org.docx4j:docx4j-ImportXHTML:jar:3.0.0 (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:4.5.1.Final (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-search-analyzers:jar:4.5.1.Final (compile), org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL (compile), org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.10-FINAL (compile), org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.44.0 (compile), org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.42.2 (test), com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1 (compile), org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.1 (compile), org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.1.0 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ibm.lotus:domingo:jar:1.5.1: Could not transfer artifact ibm.lotus:domingo:pom:1.5.1 from/to codehaus (http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus): repository.codehaus.org: Name or service not known: Unknown host repository.codehaus.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

Comment: I think it might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248317/building-oozie-unknown-host-repository-codehaus-org

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove repository.codehaus.org in repository block.

> All Codehaus services will be terminated progressively until May 17th
>   2015
>
> If you have been directed here, then the service you are accessing may
>   have been disabled already, or we are trying to get your attention by
>   blacking out services early.

Now Codehaus artifacts are in Maven Central repo

Answer (score 0):

Go to .m2 repo and find out the directory structure under repository. And remove the same. 
Clean the Java Project. It will load the required jars automatically. No need to do anything else.