# Why is my Dockerfile not building any more?

Tags: java, linux, docker, maven, dockerfile

I'm running the [Cantaloupe image server](https://cantaloupe-project.github.io/) using Docker. For this I've got a `Dockerfile` which starts with this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS base

ENV CANTALOUPE_VERSION="4.1.5"

EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
      wget unzip curl net-tools \
      graphicsmagick imagemagick ffmpeg python \
      maven default-jre
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN wget -O cantaloupe-git.zip https://github.com/cantaloupe-project/cantaloupe/archive/v${CANTALOUPE_VERSION}.zip
RUN unzip cantaloupe-git.zip

RUN cd /tmp/cantaloupe-${CANTALOUPE_VERSION} && mvn clean package -DskipTests
# and after this some more stuff..
```

This Dockerfile fails on the last line with the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cantaloupe: Could not resolve dependencies for project edu.illinois.library.cantaloupe:cantaloupe:war:4.1.5: Failed to collect dependencies at it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-tiff:jar:1.1.19 -> it.geosolutions.imageio-ext:imageio-ext-utilities:jar:1.1.19 -> javax.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3: Could not transfer artifact javax.media:jai_codec:pom:1.1.3 from/to codehaus (http://repository.codehaus.org/): repository.codehaus.org: Name or service not known: Unknown host repository.codehaus.org: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]

Of this error, the last part is interesting:

> Name or service not known: **Unknown host repository.codehaus.org**

`codehaus.org` is indeed offline, and according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31230193/1650012) it's already offline since at least 2015 (!!).

The weird thing is that

- This `Dockerfile` used to work fine until about at least a month ago.
- <s>When I run the commands on my laptop locally (also running Ubuntu) it also builds fine.</s> => I had this dependency cached locally in my m2

Also, I don't see anyone else with this issue.

Am I doing something wrong in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Possibly you have this dependency cached localy in your m2?

Comment: You probably want to update your Maven repos.

Comment: @michalk - You mean that I've got it cached on my laptop, but not in the docker container? But how could this Dockerfile have worked only about a month ago, even though that repository.codehaus.org has been offline since 2015?

Comment: @DaveNewton - Do you mean I need to update my maven repo's within the container? I'm not really a java guru, any idea how I could do that? Or do I need to update it the cantaloupe project? So I guess in this file? => https://github.com/cantaloupe-project/cantaloupe/blob/develop/pom.xml#L268

Comment: Something is pulling in jai_codec from a long-dead Maven repo; doesn't look like it's cantaloupe. Check your pom.